# Is there a way to make a blocking call in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js

It's few times harder to program using continuations (callbacks) rather than in model of straight sequential execution. Can NodeJs do blocking calls?

Comment: You can use a module like `async` to help manage the callback chain.

Comment: If all you are doing is file system access, then you can use the synchronous functions in the `fs` module. Otherwise, there is no mechanism to make an asynchronous function block. As @Joe mentions, you should work on managing callbacks more effectively. It's not hard or complex when you're used to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. For example you can read a file with fs.readFileSync() rather than fs.readFile(). Each library usually provides a xxxSync method for synchronous/blocking methods.

But you should NOT use the sync method very often. Remember that Node.js uses a single thread of execution for JavaScript code. If you block this thread you block it for everybody (unlike C#/Java where a new thread will be created for each request.)

If the asynch approach is too much for you you might want to use another platform (Ruby, Python, PHP).

Comment: it's not too much it's just brings unnecessary complexity sometimes

Comment: Some of the work being done on the language itself (like generators) or the libraries available (like async) can help with the syntax, but I hear you. Sometimes you want just a plain sequential workflow and it is not nearly as neat in Node.js as in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, node.js 0.11.x can do blocking calls inside if a generator. By "blocking call" I mean stopping execution of current function for a while. Look at [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co) library.

This is the only recommended way to do blocking calls.

Other than that, you can look at [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers), but it needs to be used carefully, and not in general-purpose libraries.

There are also a couple of *Sync calls mentioned before, but please avoid using them entirely unless you're writing one-liner.